# Elements of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, free-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $R, S$ be rings such that $R$ is a subring of $S$ and $1_R = 1_S$.

Let $N$ be a left $R$-module. Let the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on $S \times N$ be $F_\mathbb{Z}(S \times N)$. Let $H$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $F_\mathbb{Z}(S \times N)$ generated by
$$(s_1+s_2,n) - (s_1,n) - (s_2,n)\\
(s,n_1+n_2) - (s,n_1) - (s,n_2)\\
(sr,n) - (s,rn)$$
for all $s,s_1,s_2 \in S$, $n,n_1,n_2 \in N$, $r \in R$.

We can define the tensor product $S \otimes_R N$ as the quotient $F_\mathbb{Z}(S \times N)/H$.

I understand any element $x$ in $F_\mathbb{Z}(S \times N)$ can be written as a finite sum $$x = \sum \pm (s_i,n_i)$$ due to the construction of the free group. But I don't understand why for any element $y \in S \otimes_R N$, we can write $y$ as finite sum $$y = \sum s_i \otimes n_i.$$

Is there some reason why we can suddenly drop the negative coefficients after taking quotients? From what I see, this would imply
$$(s_i, n_i) + H = -(s_i, n_i) + H,$$
but why is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation $(s_1+s_2,n)-(s_1,n)-(s_2,n)$ in the case $s_2=-s_1$ implies that $s_1\otimes n+(-s_1)\otimes n=0\otimes n$.  Using the same relation with $s_1=s_2=0$ gives $0\otimes n+0\otimes n=0\otimes n$, so $0\otimes n=0$.  Thus $-(s_1\otimes n)=(-s_1)\otimes n$.

So in your expression for $y$, any term of the form $-(s_i\otimes n_i)$ can be replaced by $(-s_i)\otimes n_i$.  Doing this for all the negative terms gives a sum where every term has the form $s\otimes n$ for some $s\in S$, $n\in N$.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!